# AWS EMR Metric Server - Cluster Driver is throwing Insufficient Memory Error

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

This is in relation to my previous post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792639/aws-emr-there-is-insufficient-memory-for-the-java-runtime-environment-to-continu)) regarding the OOM I'm experiencing on a driver after running some Spark steps.

I have a cluster with 2 nodes in addition to the master, running the job as client.  It's a small job that is not very memory intensive.

I've paid particular attention to the hadoop processes via htop, they are the user generated ones and also the highest memory consumers. The main culprit is the amazon.emr.metric.server process, followed by the state pusher process.

As a test I killed the process, the memory as shown by Ganglia dropped quite drastically whereby I was then able to run 3-4 consecutive jobs before the OOM happened again. This behaviour repeats if I manually kill the process.

My question really is regarding the default behaviour of these processes and whether what I'm witnessing is the norm or whether something crazy is happening.

Comment: Can you paste the Url of the previous post please? Thanks

Comment: @MurtazaKanchwala, apologies, updated post

Comment: What is the Instance Type on EMR for Master and Cores? Are you specifying any kind of Yarn or Spark related properties? Have you set memory allocation on JDK or your Driver or Executor's JVM config? Also are you using Yarn-Client mode or Yarn-Cluster Mode?

Comment: Suggestions - 1) Can you try in Yarn-Cluster Mode 2) Copy all the required jars on the Classpath of Spark on each node 3) And allot memory to executor and driver = 70% of the Machine's Ram and try again?

Comment: What EMR release/version is being used?  I would recommend trying this on EMR 4.7.1 or later to ensure you are benefiting from latest development and improvements.

Comment: @ChristopherB, thanks for your suggestion, we have been using 4.5, I've just started one on 4.7.1 to see if it helps.

Comment: @MurtazaKanchwala - Hello, we're running in client mode but I can certainly try cluster instead.  The Spark/Yarn properties we are settings are limited to maximumresourceAllocation, dynamicAllocaton.enabled:true and kyro serialiser.We've not configured or changed any memory settings. Could you expalin how I'd go about your suggestion of copying the jars and where it's best to configure the memory option please?

Comment: @null - sometimes I got this kind of abnormal behavior due to the custom libraries not present in Spark_Classpath on each node, Plus there is more chance that things get working on Yarn-Cluster instead of client mode. And you said that you've applied maxResourceAlloc in Spark then you don't need to anything. You can try using a Bootstrap action to paste your jars in Spark_Classpath on each node from a particular S3 location, apologies I don't have exact locations with me right now.

Comment: @MurtazaKanchwala - I'm waiting on two clusters to start, one is the same but using 4.7.1, the other is both using 4.7.1 and also cluster mode.  I'm now looking into the option of copying across the dependencies to worker nodes, I've used sbt assembly to build an uber jar and thought this was already taken care of though?

Comment: @null You can try with the uber jar too. Try with Yarn-Cluster once. Please let know for the stacktrace

Comment: @MurtazaKanchwala - trying those things now, it sometimes takes some time for the problem to reveal itself / slow memory creep but I'll certainly post back as soon as it dies with the stack, thank you again for your time - much appreciated.